# How to enable Undo and Redo options in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Please help me to enable the Undo and Redo options in JMeter. There is an option to enable the Undo and Redo options in JMeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the material you need to check out, [How to undo/redo in JMeter](https://jmetervn.com/2016/09/30/how-to-undoredo-in-jmeter/)